# vector pair sorting by the difference of the pair elements

Tags: c++, sorting

Is there any way in C++, That will sort me a pairs of vector based on the difference of the pair values. As an example, Suppose I have 4 pairs

```
1 3, 
5 6, 
2 3,
12 5,
```

so, the differences of the pairs are 2 1 1 7, if I sort in descending order The sorted vector would be,

```
12 5,
1 3,
5 6,
2 3,
```

I hope you understood what my problem is. Is there any way to sort the elements this way?

I have tried this way to sort elements based on first or second element. But this is not my problem. My problem is I need sort that based on the difference.

```
bool sortinrev(const pair<int,int> &a, const pair<int,int> &b){
    return(a.first > b.first) ;
}


int main()
{
    vector< pair <int,int> > pq;
    for(int i=1; i<=4; i++){
        int x,y;
        cin >> x >> y;

        pq.push_back(make_pair(x,y));
    }

    sort(pq.begin(), pq.end(), sortinrev);

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        cout << pq[i].first << " " << pq[i].second << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The [sort function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) c++ has can take a function pointer as an argument. Just pass it a function that compares the pairs the way you want.

Comment: I only know how to sort that based on the first element or based on the second element. Since I don't know how to do sort based on difference so, I posted to know the way.Then I will try and solve my real problem.

Comment: You can pass a `compare` variable to the `sort()` method.  See the link @scohe001 has in his comment.

Comment: There are actually many ways as this is computational problem, and C++ is powerful enough to implement almost anything (although sometimes it takes time). In this particular case the C++ offers built-in support for reasonably short and elegant solution [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) (and using the comparator variant, like the answer from CoryKramer demonstrates). But the question *"Is there any way in C++"* is usually automatically "yes", unless you have some non-computational problem, or some VERY low level OS/firmware stuff.

Comment: @Ped7g yes, This is from a computational problem. I need best solution.

Comment: @YeasinRahaman "best" in what way? Short source? Short binary? Best performance? etc... you can't have all in this case, those answers below are reasonable compromise (simple source, re-using C++ stdlib in expected way, reasonable performance).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your container is

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> data;
```

you could sort it as

```
std::sort(std::begin(data),
          std::end(data),
          [](std::pair<int, int> const& lhs, std::pair<int, int> const& rhs)
          {
              return std::abs(lhs.first - lhs.second) < std::abs(rhs.first - rhs.second);
          });
```

If you want to switch between ascending and descending just switch from `<` to `>` accordingly.

Comment: Your code is perfect for this situation, but if OP didn't know how to look up and find this sort function, I doubt he'll understand lambdas. Maybe add an explanation? Or make the comparator it's own function?

Answer (score 2):

The standard library provides a data structure `std::pair` and a sorting algorithm `std::sort`, to which you can pass your custom comparison that defines the order. See the following code, that defines a comparator taking two `std::pair<int,int>` and comparing them based on their "absolute difference", together with the code how to invoke `std::sort` with it. Hope it helps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > v = {
        {1, 3},
        {5, 6},
        {2, 3},
        {12, 5}
    };

    // sort using a custom function object
    struct {
        bool operator()(const std::pair<int,int> &a, const std::pair<int,int> &b) const
        {
            return ( abs(a.first-a.second) > abs(b.first-b.second));
        }
    } differenceIsGreater;
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), differenceIsGreater);
    for (auto a : v) {
        std::cout << "(" << a.first << "," << a.second << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
(12,5)
(1,3)
(5,6)
(2,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

std::sort has an overload that takes a compare callable.

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );
```

So, you can pass a lambda (or other function) as that third parameter that tcompares any way that you want.

From cppreference.com:

```
comp     -   comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the     requirements of Compare) which returns ​true if the first argument is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second. 
The signature of the comparison function should be equivalent to the following:

bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);

The signature does not need to have const &, but the function object must not modify the objects passed to it.
The types Type1 and Type2 must be such that an object of type RandomIt can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to both of them. ​
```

So, for example

```
sort(begin(myvect), end(myvect), [](auto p) { /* comparison code */ });
```

(that requires c++14, you may have to modify that depending on your compiler version)